# how to avoid $diges on $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, performance, scope, digest, rootscope

I'm developing a large mobile app that must works on prettty old devices. And I've met with a problem of long $digest time.
Could you give me an advice, how reduce it?
I was considering of calling `$scope.$digest()` instead of `$timeout()` to prevent firing  $digest on $rootScope and update only necessary $scopes and its childs when it's needed.
 But there are another problem exist, I have to check $$phase every time when I'm calling $digest on $scope and it's looks oddly to me. I think that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: try to reduce watcher numbers, use one-way binding instead of two-way,  use `ngIf` instead of `ngShow`

Comment: thanks, I have used angular 1.3 and event didn't know about one-way binding, so your reply is wery helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use $digest most of the time.  Angular already handles this turn based events in javascript.  What you should really focus on is to use as less possible,

1. two way data binding (bind once, or pass data through events, etc)
2. two way data binding - seriously, it's the worst thing to do with this framework
3. watchers, especially the ones that watches collections
4. heavy jquery/angular element usage through dom manipulation
5. have a look at this guide, https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide